# Use the definition of convexity to show that $A$ is a convex set.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $A$ be the set of all positive semidefinite definite $n × n$ matrices in $\mathbb R_{
n×n}$
. Use the
definition of convexity to show that $A$ is a convex set.

Comment: Any nonnegative combination of "nonnegative things" (numbers, psd matrices, etc.) is again nonnegative... There is really nothing to show here. Just write it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y\in A$. Then we want to show that for all $t\in [0,1]$, $(1-t)A+tB$ is positive semi-definite. Let's show this by direct calculation. For any vector $x$:
$$x^T((1-t)A + tB)x = (1-t)(x^TAx) + t(x^TBx)$$
Now you just need to show that the above is non-negative, using the fact that $A$ and $B$ are positive semi-definite.